# Skin probability of a given pixel of a image

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

Given  RGB value's of all pixels of a image , how can we find the probability that the given pixel is of skin color and what percentage of the image is of skin color .

Comment: Your question is FAR too broad. How do you define skin colour - it varies with many factors such as race, health, degree of suntan, etc. What tolerance could you possibly attach? Your two questions also amount to the same thing.

Comment: The [processing] tag should only be used for questions about the Processing language.

Comment: @utlesh singh There are problably quite a few algorithms out there. Have you looked at RGB to YCrCb colour space conversion and then tried detection in that colour space ? (one of the [1st answers](http://www.wseas.us/e-library/conferences/2011/Mexico/CEMATH/CEMATH-20.pdf) I found on google is a paper on percentages of skin colour)

Comment: @KevinWorkman - Apologies in advance for the n00bs who keep tagging questions with Processing. A lot of the questions that deal with data or image processing have your comment and cleanup that follows with it lol. On that note, thanks for keeping the tags straight!

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks. It doesn't really bother me, but I think people would get better answers if they used correct tags. I started a meta discussion about it [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280023/processing-tag-suggested-for-general-processing-questions), but it didn't go very far.

Answer (score 6):

Noodling around on Google tells me that caucasian skin tones often, or maybe generally, or maybe sometimes conform to the following sort of rule:

```
Blue channel:  140-180
Green channel: Blue * 1.15
Red channel:   Blue * 1.5
```

So, with that in mind, I made some colour swatches that correspond to that with ImageMagick, using this command line:

```
#!/bin/bash
for b in $(seq 140 5 180); do
  g=$(echo "$b * 1.15/1" | bc)
  r=$(echo "$b * 1.5/1"  | bc)
  convert -label "R:$r,G:$g,B:$b" -size 200x200 xc:"rgb($r,$g,$b)" miff:-
done | montage - -frame 5 -tile 3x swatches.png
```

And got this:

[image]

Ok, those look kind of reasonable, now I try to use those to detect skin tones, again with ImageMagick. For the moment, and just so you can see it, I am going to colour lime-green everthing I detect as a skin-tone, using this which is right in the middle of the tonal range identified above:

```
convert -fuzz 5% face1.jpg -fill lime -opaque "rgb(240,184,160)" out.jpg
```

[image]

Mmmm, not very good. Increase the fuzziness maybe?

[image]

Mmmm, still pretty rubbish - picking up only part of the skin and some of the white shirt collar. Different face maybe?

[image]

Ok, not bad at detecting him, although notice it completely fails to detect the right side of his face, however there are still a few problems as we can see from the pink cadillac:

[image]

and Miss Piggy below...

[image]

Maybe we can be a bit more targeted in our search, and, though I can't draw it in 3-D, I can explain in 2-D. Instead of targeting a single large circle (actually sphere in 3-D space) in the middle of our range, maybe we could target some smaller circles spread along our range and thereby include fewer extraneous colours... the magenta represents the degree of fuzz. So rather than this:

[image]

we could do this:

[image]

using this command:

```
convert -fuzz 13% face1.jpg -fill lime \
   -opaque "rgb(219,168,146)"          \
   -opaque "rgb(219,168,146)"          \
   -opaque "rgb(255,198,172)" out.jpg
```

[image]

So, you can see it is pretty hard to find skin-tones just by using RGB values and I haven't even started to address different races, different lighting etc.

Another approach may be to use a different colourspace, such as HSL - Hue Saturation and Lightness. We are not so interested in Lightness because that is just a function of exposure, so we look for hues that match those of skin and some degree of saturation to avoid washed out colours. You can do that with ImageMagick like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
convert face1.jpg -colorspace hsl -separate          \
   \( -clone 0 -threshold 7% -negate +write h.png \) \
   \( -clone 1 -threshold 30% +write s.png        \) \
   -delete 0-2 -evaluate-sequence min out.png
```

That says this... take the image `face1.jpg` and convert it to HSL colorspace, then separate the layers so we now have 3 images in our stack. `image 0` is the Hue, `image 1` is the Saturation and `image 2` is the Lightness. Next line. Take the Hue layer and threshold it at 7% which means pinky-reds, invert it and save it (just so you can see it) as `h.png`. Next line. Take the Saturation layer, and say "*any saturation over 30% is good enough for me*", then save as file `s.png`. Next line. Delete the 3 original layers (HS&L) from the original image leaving just the thresholded Hue and thresholded Saturation layers. Now put these ontop of each other and choose whichever is the minimum and save that. The point is that either the Hue or the Saturation layer can be used to `gate` which pixels are selected.

Here are the files, first the Hue (`h.png`):

[image]

next the Saturation (`s.png`):

[image]

and now the combined output file.

[image]

Once you have got your algorithm sorted out for deciding which pixels are skin coloured, you will need to count them to work out the percentages you seek. That is pretty easy... all we do is change everything that is not lime-green to black (so it counts for zero in the averaging) and then resize the image to a single pixel and get its colour as text:

```
convert -fuzz 13% face1.jpg -fill lime      \
    -opaque "rgb(219,168,146)"              \
    -opaque "rgb(219,168,146)"              \
    -opaque "rgb(255,198,172)"              \
    -fill black +opaque lime -resize 1x1! txt:

# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,1,255,srgb
0,0: (0,92,0)  #005C00  srgb(0,92,0)
```

We can see there is, not surprisingly, no red and no blue and the average colour of the green pixels is 92/255, so 36% of pixels match our description of skin-toned.

If you want to get more sophisticated you may have to look at shapes, textures and contexts, or train a skin classifier and write a whole bunch of stuff in OpenCV or somesuch...

Comment: That is just epic. Love the Rowan Atkinson use. +1

Comment: Interesting... now try it with the other 2/3 of the world's population. ;)

Comment: Since writing this, the following paper came to my attention... https://www.graphicon.ru/oldgr/en/publications/text/gc2003vsa.pdf